# Share headers between two projects

Tags: c++, oop, client-server, visual-studio-2013

My project is in Visual Studio Express 2013. I have one *Solution* for my game called **Game**. Within the solution I have two *Projects* one called **Client** and one called **Server**. I wrote a *Class* called **Game**. I also wrote *two more Classes*, **Client** and **Server**, both inherit from the **Game** *class*. I have separate .cpp and .h files for each class. How can I use these files in both projects? I'd like to create a Client object in the client project and a Server object in the server project. Is this possible? Am I going about this the wrong way? I'm trying to use classes more.

Comment: Create both projects in the same solution. Create a library with the shared code in that same solution.

Comment: Ok thank you. Both projects are currently in the same solution. I guess I'll now research libraries.

Comment: For simplicity I recommend a static library.

Comment: Also add the location of the library folder in the Additional Include Directories for the Client and Server projects. You can use relative paths like ..\MyLibrary

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just watched a video comparing static and dynamic libraries and I agree, a static library appears to be the best option. I'm currently dynamically linking to the SFML library in both client and server projects. The code I'd like to write for my library would also need to reference SFML. Is it possible for my library to link to another library?

Comment: Your lib can use the dll.

Comment: Ok great thanks, do you know of any good resources on how to create a static library?

Comment: No sorry. Its been way too long (nearly 2 decades) since I have looked for this type of info..